# Error converting String to java.sql.LocalDateTime

Tags: java

I tried converting string to LocalDateTime. Here is my code

```
String val = "2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400"
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
java.time.LocalDateTime dateTime = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(val, formatter);
```

But doing so I am getting the following errors

```
The method ofPattern(String) is undefined for the type DateTimeFormatter
The method parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter) in the type LocalDateTime is not applicable for the arguments (String, DateTimeFormatter)
```

Can someone suggest me what to do

Comment: What is the package of this `DateTimeFormatter`  class ?

Comment: Check which `DateTimeFormatter` type you're using. My guess is that you've also got Joda Time in the project.

Comment: You have `-` in your sample string. Is this is a typo ? Otherwise try removing `-` from string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading `-` from your String.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String val = "2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(val, formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

> 2015-07-18T13:32:56.971

Comment: As @Jon SKeet told I had imported org.joda.DateTimeFomratter too that was the issue.. not "-"

Comment: But the leading "-" is also an issue: Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for YearOfEra (valid values 1 - 999999999/1000000000): -2015

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly right. First, be sure you're importing the correct packages:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Second, your first line has a typo (-) in the first character of the String val and is missing a semicolon:

```
// Remove - from the String and put ; at the end
// String val = "-2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400"
String val = "2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
LocalDateTime dateTime = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(val, formatter);
//Print to test:
System.out.println(dateTime);
//Result on the console: 2015-07-18T13:32:56.971
```